# Yahoo Pipes : rss feed source Error?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

i want to know if everyone is able to see the [following](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=gX6zUbmTiZ8Xk9DYCva__ITpLokoAmTZpASHhRYqYkI4-y9ygjOouyT1wW3zVqfPvTJeoB51eSUF1uBNnrOdX0Ca7qkxG-AVm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnFxaYc6GIijDhscoufaRfGaGTvRSfNop4NBZzEpxVXeODMbkDKfYwPS7scWYSCz-orFuq7IVj2xyuyFFanCEzplPVH40WZiiUR_LfmYbIuwY&lib=M-HuCTwEJYePNCQj8khcWIIM8auVI7v_L) URL successfully, because i am able to do so.

but then, i try to use the URL above as my feed source in yahoo pipes, they show the following error :

`Error fetching https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=gX6zUbmTiZ8Xk9DYCva__ITpLokoAmTZpASHhRYqYkI4-y9ygjOouyT1wW3zVqfPvTJeoB51eSUF1uBNnrOdX0Ca7qkxG-AVm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnFxaYc6GIijDhscoufaRfGaGTvRSfNop4NBZzEpxVXeODMbkDKfYwPS7scWYSCz-orFuq7IVj2xyuyFFanCEzplPVH40WZiiUR_LfmYbIuwY&lib=M-HuCTwEJYePNCQj8khcWIIM8auVI7v_L. Response: OK (200). Error: Invalid XML document. Root cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 921; columnNumber: 5; The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag " ".`

how can i resolve this problem ? i try to use different tools on source modules, keep showing the same error.

i don't know if the error either comes from yahoo pipes or my rss url, or even something else.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a Fetch Data module with a "Path to item list" set to "entry".

I took it [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Pipes/Error-Invalid-XML-document-Root-cause-/1366982805511-8ebc6f55-32a0-44f2-800d-b0e906b9a06f/) and it works for me.